# Search and replace 'dh $@' with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace this string

```
dh $@
```

with that one

```
dh $@ --foobar
```

I tried this

```
sed --expression "s/dh $@/dh $@ --foobar/" file
```

But of course there is the blank and the $ makeing "problems".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes around the pattern to avoid shell variable expansion from expanding the `$@` to the empty string (or whatever other contents the positional parameters contain.

```
sed --expression 's/dh $@/dh $@ --foobar/' file
```

You could also use `&` in the replacement to avoid needing to duplicate the pattern. (`&` in the replacement means the entirety of the match.)

```
sed --expression 's/dh $@/& --foobar/' file
```

Comment: i think you mean `\$` instead of `$`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr You can do that but in this case you don't need to it would seem. The end-of-line meaning of `$` doesn't really make sense in the middle of the pattern and is presumably ignored (at least by the version of gnu sed I'm testing with).

Comment: @EtanReisner well sed!

Comment: what is the use of `--expression`??? btw `$` means end-of-string, not end-of-line. It's just that in sed you're usually comparing with a string that ends at the end of the line so the meanings get mixed up which can bite you later with other tools or when using sed with a multi-line string in one of those "space" thingies (hold space?).

Comment: @EdMorton `-e`/`--expression`. Often you don't need it, as the first and only non-option argument is implicitly the script, but if you have more than script block or a file *and* a script block or a script block that starts with a `-` then you need it. And yeah, that line/string thing gets confused in sed because of how it works. I should be more careful how I talk about it.

Comment: Ah, `-e` I know, just never came across `--expression` before. Wonder what would inspire anyone to use THAT as an option... Thanks.

Comment: To clarify (GNU sed): `$` as a metacharacter refers to the end of the pattern space except when the multiline flag is envoked (`/../M or s/.../.../M`) when it refers to the zero space before a `\n` and `\'` refers to end of pattern space.